# How can i have multiple acceleration rate in 1 bezier curves in css

Tags: html, css

let say that I want to make an animation in css that start with an acceleration of 0 and that gradualy go faster for x seconde, than after that, it stop accelerating and keep the actual speed of the animation?

I tried to combine the ease-in function with the linear, but when it switch, I can observe a drastic deceleration, so it's not smooth. The html and css in question

Here is the HTML

```html
<div.marquee>
<img>
<img>
<img>
```

Here is the CSS

````css
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
.marquee{animation: marquee 30s ease-in 2.1s 1, marquee 30s linear 32.1s infinite;}```

Edit. Ok so for more context, the code that I have up there would cause
something like this to my animation : https://imgur.com/wgulJxH, while what
I want is an animation that those this : https://imgur.com/oyjQTtE
````

Comment: Please show some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: And the property for the animation is there `  animation: marquee 30s ease-in 2.1s 1, marquee 30s linear 32.1s infinite;`

Comment: please edit your question to add the code there, not in a comment . Please try to make a  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: CSS supports custom cubic beziers. it sounds like you want [something like this](https://cubic-bezier.com/#.63,.11,.01,.1) steeper in height means faster animation. flatter will make it slower. your can curve it like you want.

Comment: The velocity (or angular velocity - if you're i.e: rotating your element) at the finish of a 3s ease-in is not the same as the linear angular velocity for the same period of 3s. Also, Don't use 3.1s pause (or 31 as you do) for the infinite linear animation; use the same length of 3s for the pause. After a quick try (not mathematically supported) an approximation is to lower the duration of the linear animation to 2/3 of the ease-in one: something like `2s`. Example: `animation: marquee 3s ease-in 0s, marquee 2s linear 3s infinite;` https://jsfiddle.net/dhqtz7pr/

Comment: The reason I use a decimal for my pause is that I have other animation before this animation and I want clear difference between my animation. But yeah, thanks I will try this and do testing on my side to see if this work

Comment: Ok so, now this seems to work, now I<ll have to find a way to slow down this and fix a little bug where the transition between 2 same animation have a little bump, so it<s not perfectly smooth. But thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've done some testing, and this solution submitted by Roko C. Buljan seems to work. By dividing the second function time by 2 seems to fix the problem. If the first function is 30s, the second with a linear function should be 20s long. Here is an example

```css
  animation: marquee 30s ease-in 0s 1, marquee 20s linear 30s infinite;
```

Thank you Roko C. Buljan for this answer